# Wait for helm delete before proceeding?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a pipeline with helm v2 commands which looks like this:

```
  helm delete --purge nginx-ingress || true
  helm upgrade -i nginx-ingress --values _INFRA/nginx-ingress/${ENV}.yaml stable/nginx-ingress
```

It worked well until two weeks ago. Not sure what caused it, the script itself hasn't changed and neither did the files involved. I suspect a kubernetes update from 1.14 to 1.17, but it now generates this kind of errors:

```
$ helm delete --purge nginx-ingress || true # collapsed multi-line command
release "nginx-ingress" deleted
Release "nginx-ingress" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: release nginx-ingress failed: object is being deleted: services "nginx-ingress-controller" already exists
```

Looks like helm delete became asynchronous or something.

**How can I make this script wait for the process of nginx-ingress to be deleted for proceeding with the next command ?**

Comment: dont think this is possible [see here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2378)